# Creating an index in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I'm trying to create an index like it's shown in the screenshot below. This one was done by simply adding programmatically texboxes to horizontal- and vertical stackpanels inside an scrollviewer. But this solution was incredible slow. The binding took about 5 seconds.

[image]

Therefore I tested to bind a `List<>` containing the whole data directly to a `ListBox`. I tried various combinations of `ItemTemplates` but even by using `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"` it wasn't able for me to speed up the binding. Only a simple `ListBox` without any attempts of grouping did the job.

That's the only XML-part I used for all my tests:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,5">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{DynamicResource HoverUnderlineStyle}" MouseLeftButtonUp="...">
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                    <!-- ... -->
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat=" ({0})">
                <Binding Path="Count"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

It would be really great if someone could help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which control should contain the text? A TextBlock or a TextBox? (You wrote TextBox, but in the screenshot they look like textblocks). And do you want the items to be selectable?

Comment: Oh sorry for the mistake! A TextBlock and yes the items should to be selectable.

Comment: what is the actual question, are you asking for a better performing solution?

Comment: @tron That's a lot of data you're showing, and in result a lot of controls that need to be drawn.  So much data that the human brain can't process all of it at once.  Why not make it easier for the user to find someone by using a search, or start groups in a collapsed state. I don't know, something that doesn't cause information overload.

Comment: Also, styles can have significant impact on rendering times.  Lastly, you could also look up how to use a HeaderedItemsControl, or a customized ItemsControl for your case depending on if you need the items clickable or selectable (there is a difference).

Answer (score 0):

I think that should work:
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Value"
             ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(RandomString(8));
        }

        CollectionView =
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(list.OrderBy(x => x[0]).Select(x => new TestItem {Value = x}));
        CollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Value", new FirstLetterConverter()));
    }

    public ICollectionView CollectionView { get; set; }

    public static string RandomString(int length)
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
            .Select(s => s[Random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }
}

public class TestItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class FirstLetterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string s = value as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return s.Substring(0, 1);
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

If that is to slow for you, you could search for a wrap panel which supports virtualizing, because that is not supported by the .net framework.

Preview:
[image: Preview]

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I will test it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can point out a couple of improvements to your Xaml:

1. Try using `StaticResource` instead of a `DynamicResource`.
2. You don't really need a `MultiBinding` in your second textblock. In fact, you might use a single `TextBlock` with multiple `Run`s, and get rid of the `StackPanel`.

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HoverUnderlineStyle}" MouseLeftButtonUp="...">
    ...
    <Run Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Count, StringFormat={} ({0})}"/>
</TextBlock>
```